# Convert Optional to boolean in functional style

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I just wanted to return a `boolean` from an `Optional` object by doing a check on the `getProductType()` on the `ProductDetails` object as shown below:

```
public boolean isElectronicProduct(String productName) {
    Optional<ProductDetails> optProductDetails = findProductDetails(productName);
    if(optProductDetails.isPresent()) {
        return optProductDetails.get().getProductType() == ProductType.ELECTRONICS;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Intellij complains stating that the above code can be replaced in functional style, is there really any way to simplify the above `Optional` object and return a `boolean`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
optProductDetails.map(d -> d.getProductType() == ProductType.ELECTRONICS) //Optional<Boolean>
                 .orElse(false); //Boolean
```

Answer (score 8):

Change this:

```
if(optProductDetails.isPresent()) {
    return optProductDetails.get().getProductType() == ProductType.ELECTRONICS;
}
return false;
```

**To**:

```
return optProductDetails
      .filter(prodDet -> prodDet.getProductType() == ProductType.ELECTRONICS)  // Optional<ProductDetails> which match the criteria
      .isPresent();   // boolean
```

You can read more about functional-style operations on `Optional` values at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Answer (score 8):

This is what you need:

```
return findProductDetails(productName)
    .map(ProductDetails::getProductType)
    .map(ProductType.ELECTRONICS::equals)
    .orElse(false);
```

I prefer to split things out with the extra `map` call, rather than calling `productDetails.getProductType()` directly before the comparison. I think it's just slightly easier to read.